# Training a new dataset on bert

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, tokenize, bert-language-model

I have a amazon review dataset, where I want to predict the star rating based on the review

I know I can use a pretrained bert model as shown [here](https://github.com/nicknochnack/BERTSentiment/blob/main/Sentiment.ipynb)

But I want to train the bert model on my own dataset. Is that whats being done [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/fine-tuning-bert-for-amazon-food-reviews-32e474de0e51)? And can I apply this type of 'fine tuning' on a pretrained model with any dataset to get more accurate results or do I have to do something else to train the model from scratch

And if I do want to train a model from scratch, where would I start

Answer (score 0):

First of all what is pretraining? The procedure helps the model to learn syntactic <==> semantic (this is a spectrum) features of the language using an enormous amount of raw text (40GB) and processing power. objective function: casual language model and mask language model

What about fine-tuning a pre-trained model? suppose there is a model which has knowledge about the general aspect of the English language (POS, dependency tree, subj ... a little of everything). fine-tuning help us to direct the focus of the model on the most important features in our dataset, let's say in your dataset some syntactic feature is the game-changer, and the model should be careful about it!
objective function: based on downstream task

Training from scratch isn't feasible for most of us, but there is an approach to continue the pre-training phase using your own corpus/corpora (task-specific) without damaging model pieces of knowledge (hopefully)!
objective function: casual language model and mask language model

[Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.06146.pdf) is an article about this approach and its effectiveness and you can be inspired by [Scibert](https://github.com/allenai/scibert) and [COVIDbert](https://github.com/manueltonneau/covid-berts). As you expect the use pre-trained bert as a starting point and continue pre-training using domain-specified corpus!

Comment: ok that makes it a lot clearer.
to clarify, if i download a pretrained bert model from[here](https://huggingface.co/models?sort=downloads) and follow the steps of this [article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/fine-tuning-bert-for-amazon-food-reviews-32e474de0e51) but with my own dataset, I will be able to get better results than just the pretrained model, correct?

Comment: As you might consider the article you mentioned is trying to fine-tune the existing pre-trained model on a downstream task, moreover the objective function is classification error! In the further pre-training procedure objective function is Language Modeling related error. Please watch this [Article](https://towardsdatascience.com/maximizing-bert-model-performance-539c762132ab)